# jquery infinite slider images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create an infinite slider using jquery. My page has some  tags, with the width equal to the window width.

I want to slide every image after 10 seconds, and when the last image comes up and it's time for the first image to show, I want it to come still from the right.

Now I created a div with a big width, 10000px to hold my unordered list of images and they have display:none. My question is why when I'm giving margin-left: -1000px for one list item, the images appear to overlap one above the other, instead of appearing one after the other. I tried to take a screenshot but I don't know what is happening with my dropbox.

This is my CSS:

```
.slider {
    position: relative;
    height: 498px;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    overflow: hidden;
}
 .slider-list  {
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 10000px
    /*height: 496px;*/
}

.slider-list li{
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    /*width: 100%;*/
    height: 496px;  
    z-index: 1;
```

And here is my HTML:

```
<div class="slider">
        <ul class="slider-list">
            <li><img class="homepage-img"src="images/homepage.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="homepage-img"src="images/image1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="homepage-img"src="images/image2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="homepage-img"src="images/image3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img class="homepage-img"src="images/image4.jpg"></li>

        </ul>
```

The div with the class .slider will close after some more elements.

UPDATE:

This is my jQuery code since I written this post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        slide();

});

    slide = function() {
    var img = $('.homepage-img');
    var content = $('.slider-content');
    var slider = $('.slider-list');
    var elements = $('.slider-list li').children();
    var auto_slide_speed = 100;//ms
    var timer;
    var i = 0;

    img.width($(window).width());
    $("li").width($(window).width());
    img.height($('.slider-list').height());
    content.height($('.slider-list').height());

    var img_width = $('.slider-list li').outerWidth();
    console.log($('.slider-list li').length);
    console.log(elements);
    //calculam margin-left = -latimea unei imagini
    // while(1)
    // {
        var left = parseInt(slider.css('margin-left')) - img_width;
    for(i = 0; i <= $('.slider-list li').length; i++)
    {
        console.log(i);

        slider.animate({
        "margin-left": "+=" + left}, 
        1500, 
        function() {
        // $('.slider-list li:last').after($('.slider-list li:first'));
        // $('slider').css({'margin-left' : '0px'});  

        });
        // left = left + left;
        // $('slider li').append($(elements[i]).clone());
    }

    console.log(i);

}
```

With this, my slider ony goes as far as my list goes. How do I append the first item after the last item and so on so it can be infinite?

Comment: When you hit the last item; You can clone the first listitem and append it at the end of the unordered list. Whenever the animation slides to the cloned item and is done animating, shift the position to the start(You won't notice that it jumps from for example -3000px to 0px) and remove the clone again.

Comment: one of the usual trick is to have X+1 image (assuming you have X number of different images) where the first and the last is the same. When the final image slide-in, secretly reset the slider list, because the last and first image is the same, user will not notice.

Comment: I can't seem to succeed to append the images at the end of my list so I can slide infinitely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8a7Mm/8/) that will get you started.

1. Put all your images in a hidden div
2. Clone them and put them in the visible div
3. Animate the image by changing the left margin
4. You can adjust the time between images by the set interval function
5. You can adjust the slidein time by the animate time.
6. Because it's an infinite loop, I put the button in to stop the animation any time you want.

JS

```
var pictxtnumber = 1;
loadpictxt(pictxtnumber);

var fadeintime = 500;
animatediv();

function animatediv()
{
    var number = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() { 
                                           pictxtnumber = pictxtnumber + 1;
                                           if(pictxtnumber > 6)
                                             {
                                              pictxtnumber = 1;
                                              }
                                           loadpictxt(pictxtnumber);
                                           $('#stopanim').on('click', function(){
                                                                                 clearInterval(interval);
                                                                                 });
                                           }, 1000);
}

function loadpictxt(num)
{
  $('.picturediv').html('');
  $(".hiddenimage img:nth-child(" + num + ") ").clone().appendTo('.picturediv');
  $('.picturediv img').css('margin-left', '100px');
  $('.picturediv img').animate({marginLeft: "0"}, 100);    
}
```

Comment: This looks solid. I've been trying to do it with animate function. Can you take a look on my code and tell me where I can improve in order to achieve the results I need? Thank you sir.

Comment: Well, I see lots of code that has to do with sizing and measuring sizes. I think you might move most of that over to CSS to make the js simpler. In terms of the loop, you are using a for loop, which will limit you to one pass through the list of images. In an infinite loop, you can arbitrarily set a variable, say "counter", increment the counter, then when you get to the end of the number of images, reset the counter to the first image. One of the things I've learned on this forum is to try to do everything you can in HTML and CSS, thus making the JS simpler.

Answer (score 3):

If you are targeting modern browsers that support transitions and transforms i would do it that way..

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/dbLu5/

**jQuery**

```
var slides = $('.slider-list li'); // cache a reference to the slides

setInterval(function(){
    var current = slides.filter('.current'), // find slide in view
        next = current.next(); // find next slide

    if (!next.length){next = slides.first();} // loop if at last slide

    slides.removeClass('off'); // reposition already viewed slides to the right
    current.removeClass('current').addClass('off'); // set current slide to animate left
    next.removeClass('off').addClass('current'); // set next slide to slide in view
}, 10000); // set the interval
```

**CSS** (*you need to add vendor prefixes for the transform and transition properties*)

```
.slider-list {
    position:relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 496px;
}
.slider-list li {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    transition:transform 1s;
    transform:translateX(100%);
    left:0; top:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.slider-list li.current{
    transform:translateX(0%);
    z-index:100;
}
.slider-list li.off{
    transform:translateX(-100%);
    z-index:100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made two simple jquery plugins for that:

- https://github.com/lingtalfi/jItemSlider
- https://github.com/lingtalfi/jInfiniteSlider

I recommend the item slider because the items are forced to be aligned, and it's simpler in the end.

Now to answer your question: How do I append the first item after the last item and so on so it can be infinite?

You could just display your slider items two times (or more) in a row.
Given your html code:

```
var jSliderList = $(".slider-list");
var jSliderOriginalItems = $("li", jSliderList); // keep track of this one

function init(){
    jSliderList.append(jSliderOriginalItems.clone()); // should work, not tested
}
```

Then with css, you would narrow the slider to the width of your choice.

Suggestions:

I would suggest that you append a page rather than just one item.

A basic approach would be to encapsulate things into functions, like this:

```
slideToRight()
    appendItemsToTheRight()
    removeUnecessaryItemsToTheLeft()
    slide()
```

To perform the slide, you could use css transitions.
In your css, put something like this:

```
.sliderContainer {   
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}
```

And then in your js code, to slide, just use a function such as:

```
function moveSlider(the_offset) {
    jSliderContent.css({
        transform: "translate3d(" + the_offset + "px, 0px, 0px)"
    });
}
```

Now to actually append an item, you could use a renderItem function to generate them, instead of cloning things.