# Two image slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently working on creating a carousel. I need to make it so I have two images side by side. When you click on the right arrow to switch them, I need the right image to go left, and a new one to take place of the right image. Then when you click left it will go backwards. I don't need animations or anything. Below is the concept image. (the carousel will be 100% width of the page, so each displayed image needs to be 50% wide.)

[image]

Here is what I have coded so far.. In my project I'm using Bootstrap and Wordpress as well.

```
<div class="wrapper">

<ul class="dual-slider">

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></li>

    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" /></a></li>

</ul>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrandonRhino/qaxu6un1/5/ (EDITED LINK TO NEW ONE)

I'm new to javascript and have no idea how to start, if someone could help point me in the right direction or help me out, I'd be beyond thankful!

Comment: All those links are to the same image. Make three placeholders -- green/blue, blue/red (this one), red/yellow. Now think through which arrows should link to which images. (Hint: put numbers in the images.)

Comment: @cphlewis  http://jsfiddle.net/BrandonRhino/qaxu6un1/5/ here is the one with the new images. Now i need to figure out how to get everything to slider right/right one space when the arrows are clicked.

Comment: Have you written *any* JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: @j08691 I haven't for a few years. I tried to look up online about this kind of stuff but everything slider related just involves one image at a time, not two.

Comment: Start with FAKING a slider. What image should the left-arrow link to? Should that target image have the same images in its arrow-links?

Comment: also, this isn't so much a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034088/jquery-infinite-slider-images?rq=1 as a subset of it. Check that out.