# how to show image circularly in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I implemented image slider using `jquery` .But it is not circularly .It mean currently it show `1->2->3..->8` then back to `zero` margin. it not look good. how i will append after last element `1->2->3..->8->1->2-3` so that it will look good.

here is my code

```
$(function(){
  var counter =0
  var len =$('.imageSlilder ul li').length;
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.imageSlilder ul').css('margin-left',-325*counter+'px')

    counter++;
       if(counter>=len){
                    counter =0
                }
    },2000)
})
```

https://jsbin.com/zizegixoha/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Here is the good example to start with https://stackoverflow.com/a/24036203/2630817

Comment: @Justcode thanks for sharing can I will add this logic in my example

Comment: copy the first image to the last position also, then if(counter>=len) reset margin-left to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the first image at the last position also, then simply reset the position to 0 without a transition:

```
 if(counter>=len+1){
      $('.imageSlilder ul').css({
        'margin-left':'0px',
        transition:'margin-left 0s'
     })
  counter=1
  }
```

to reinit the transition, may set it back:

```
$('.imageSlilder ul').css({
   'margin-left':-325*counter+'px',
   transition:'margin-left 1s'
  })
```

current approach, needs some optimizations to run smooth:

https://jsbin.com/qaruwadiwi/1/edit?js

Comment: any suggestion for some optimization ?

Comment: @naveen i think some images are not having the exact size, thats why theres a few pixel wrong offset..

Answer (score 0):

I think that a better approach than using margins is to make a copy of the first item to the last position and then remove it from its former place, so you'll have your infinite slider.

For a softer animation, you could reduce the width of the image before removal.

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        var first = $('.imageSlilder ul').children().first(); // item to move
        $('.imageSlilder ul').append(first.clone()); // CLONE it at the end
        first.animate( {width: 0}, 500, function() { // reduce width to 0
            first.remove(); // on completion of the animation, remove item
        });
    },2000)
});
```

Here you have it working: https://jsbin.com/malehufifu/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: please remove your anser

Comment: It does exactly what yours did, but with infinite scroll... please, check the link above.

Comment: see @just code comment ..what I want ..I am trying to implement that